move database from elastic pool to Azure database
We have to move database from elastic pool to Azure database,
Could you please guide how this can be achieved.
I see only option to remove database from Elastic pool but once we remove the database from elastic pool how to move to azure database.
Thanks

Databases that are part of an Azure SQL Elastic Pool are all Azure SQL databases. Once the database is removed from the elastic pool, it will be a standalone Azure SQL database. You will find it by examining the Azure SQL logical server databases.

